# after deploy django code to aws, datas in django admin are gone

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I am new in Django, python , and AWS. I register a user, and I can see the user in my Django admin deployed to AWS. After I write a new feature and 'eb deploy' to AWS. I can see the new feature, but the user I registered before disappear.  Can any one help?

Comment: This is my first time to post a question in stackoverflow. And I have only learned Django, python, AWS for one month. please let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@zijila The database is not going to carry over. It is probably a SQLite database for testing purposes. You probably wiped that DB out when you deployed using AWS EB. You should set up a MySQL database in AWS using Aws RDS. add the connection string to that DB and create a new user. That way the user is persisted when you redeploy.

Tip: Try not to write in the answer field when you respond on StackOverflow. Use the comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Dave.